# Bash menu with multiple parameters in one row

Tags: bash, shell-script, scripting

I have searched a couple of days and still didn't found the answer. I hope that you can point me in right direction.

I would like to know how to write a bash script with a options, that can be 
called in one row, such as: `script.sh -a -b -c`. Parameters which aren't chosen are ignored.

Menu/options should be like:

```
-a description: something
-b description: something else
-c description: something different
-d description: something..
```

is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The usual way of handling switches and arguments is with the `getopts` function. In `bash` this is a builtin and you can find information about it in the bash man page (`man bash`).

Essentially, you declare a string that tells `getopts` what parameters to expect, and whether they should have an argument. It's `getopts` that handles bunched parameters (eg `-abc` being equivalent to `-a -b -c`) and the parsing of the command line. At the end of the `getopts` processing you have the remainder of the command line to handle as you see fit.

A typical script segment could look something like this

```
ARG_A= FLAG_B= FLAG_C=
while getopts 'a:bc' OPT    # -a {argument}, -b, -c
do
    case "$OPT" in
        a)    ARG_A="$OPTARG" ;;
        b)    FLAG_B=yes ;;
        c)    FLAG_C=yes ;;
        *)    echo "ERROR: the options are -a {arg}, -b, -c" >&2; exit 1 ;;
    esac
done
shift $(($OPTIND - 1))

echo "Remaining command line: $*"
```

You can add `?` as a command option if you want a *nice* usage message. Remember that in the `case` block you would need to quote it or prefix it with a backslash so it's treated as a literal.

If you're wanting to run this under a different shell that doesn't have the builtin, or if you want to use *long arguments* such as `--verbose` instead of just `-v` take a look at the `getopt` utility. This is not a builtin but has been written to deliver in the more sophisticated situation.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to use any Bash-specific features to do this:

```
#!/bin/sh
while true
do
    case "$1" in
        -a)  echo Saw -a!  ;;
        -b)  echo Saw -b!  ;;
        -c)  echo Saw -c!  ;;
        -?)  cat <<USAGE
usage: $0 [-a] [-b] [-c] args

    You cannot currently combine options, as with -ac.
USAGE
            exit 1
            ;;
        *)
            echo End of options!
            break;
            ;;
    esac

    shift       # toss current $1; we're done with it now
done

for p in "$@"
do
    echo "Non-option argument: '$p'"
done
```

Unlike the code in [roaima's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/186098/138), mine is portable shell script code. It will run on any Bourne type Unix shell going back to about 1980 or so.

I think the `-?` handler answers your "menu" requirement. The `<<USAGE` construct is called a [heredoc](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html).